# merging 2 branch of the same project that were not maintained by a version control software

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have 2 project which branched from the same main code. Unfortunately they don't have version control system initialized in them. By considering they don't have that much of a difference, is there a way to automatically merge them? or at least see the differences of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git init merged_projects
cd !$

git --work-tree=/path/to/main/project git add -A .     # from empty index to base project
git commit -m'Initial commit'

git checkout -b projectA                               # from base project to projectA
git --work-tree=/path/to/projectA git add -A .
git commit -m'Initial project A commit'

git checkout -b projectB                               # projectB now, 
git reset master                                       # reset index+parent back to base
git --work-tree=/path/to/projectB git add -A .
git commit -m'Initial project B commit'
```

Git's all about constructing and working with useful histories. What you're after is right up its alley.  If you want, you can do `git init .` in any of the preexisting worktrees instead of the first two commands above.  A `git reset --hard` will reset the worktree to the committed state.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Bash try this `diff -r 1st_dir 2nd_dir` which will show you the differences between directories. Alternatively nothing in your question seems to prevent you from initializing a git repo in each directory and then merging them that way. Hope this helps.